# Issue with Javascript Auto Post Form

Tags: javascript

I'm using Javascript to auto post a form,
but I seem to be getting a lot of people telling me it doesn't work for them.

This is very important because the form is linked with my payments :/

Prehaps I am using an outdated way of doing it, any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('paypal_form').submit();
</script>
```

And here is the form (simplified):

```
<form method="POST" id="paypal_form" name="paypal_form" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" style="margin: 0; padding: 0; display: block; clear: both;">

<input type="submit" value="Click here if your browser does not automatically redirect you." style="margin: 0; margin-top: 12px; margin-bottom: 0px; font-size: 11px; padding=left: 4px; padding-right: 4px; padding-top: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px;">
</form>
```

Comment: Good point Martin, it does: http://pastebin.com/a0xie3PF

Comment: That markup is malformed, there seem to be multiple unbalanced tags. Browsers can cope with most problems but not missing `</div>` closing tags. If that page is your real markup, make sure you at least close all `<div>` tags properly and that might alleviate the problem.

Comment: Where did you find the missing tag?

Comment: neither `<div id="wrapper_bg">` nor `<div id="footer">` have closing tags. Validate your markup with [W3C's validator](http://validator.w3.org/)

Comment: The footer one would be my fault for removing some data for you, any good place to put the others end tag?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the people telling you that it doesn't work have javascript disabled. What does that submit() function look like?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have asked them that same question.

Comment: Yeah, that would be my guess. It's usually not a good idea to have a client side scripting language like javascript handle the form submission. That's usually left for server side programming languages.

Comment: The weird thing is that there is a submit button, so a user can submit if the Javascript fails, but that doesn't seem to work either for them. I mean, I'm talking about 30 users have told me this :/